# What is the most efficient way to standardize time formats and find time durations exceeding specific lengths using Excel 2007?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, format

**THE SCENARIO:**  Let’s say somebody hands you a spreadsheet containing a column for the time duration of 416,000 videos.  When the information was entered, it was entered into an Excel 2007 spreadsheet without any pre-formatting of the column.  If the duration of a video was 8 minutes and 10 seconds, it was entered as 8:10.  If it was 1 hour, 31 minutes, and 38 seconds, it was entered as 1:31:38.  Excel’s default seems to identify this as clock times in h:mm or h:mm:ss format.

When you change the format to the time format 37:30:55 (one of Excel’s default formatting options), Excel returns 8:10:00 for the first example and 1:31:38 for the second.  You happen to know that the video for 8:10 is an 8 minute, 10 second video (not an 8 hour, 10 minute video).  Based off of other research you’ve done with this type of video content, you suspect that only two out of every 10 videos are likely to be more than an hour long.  You have a way of corroborating the length of each video, but you don’t want to do it for all 416,000.  Time is of the essence.  You need to identify and send off videos of an hour or longer to another agency as soon as possible.

**OBJECTIVE #1: DISPLAYING AND SORTING TIME FORMATS:**  Without changing the original times entered, you would like to display and sort by *time displayed format* to further examine and validate how you think Excel interpreted these values and report that information with some degree of confidence.  An inspection of a random subset of these records might suffice.  You know how to work with the RAND function, you just don’t know how to display and sort by time format.  Though you suspect Excel only interpreted these values as h:mm or h:mm:ss, you need to be certain and want to conduct a random inspection of each type.  You basically want to know if Excel was consistent in its interpretation and if not, why not?  You were hoping that you could use Excel’s search box (i.e., Find and Replace), but searching by time format does not seem to be an option.

**OBJECTIVE #2: RETRIEVING VIDEOS > 60 MINUTES IN DURATION:**  If displaying and sorting by time format is not an option, you can live with that, but, at the very least, you want to pull any video that is displayed with hours, minutes, and seconds.  (You feel reasonably certain these will be videos >60 minutes in duration, but you want to randomly validate that assumption before sending them off.)  You also want to make sure no video is listed as 60:00 or 90:00 or 120:00 or any other time length >60 with the h:mm format.  You feel pretty confident that if these were just numbers, you could set up some conditional formula that would return such information, but you'd rather not do that if it isn't necessary.  However, your initial experiments using the time format don’t seem to be working.

**PREVIOUS EXPERIMENTS:**  You’ve thought about or tried some of the following:

- using the tools in conditional formatting
- using the tools with the filtering feature

These do not seem to recognize time formats when used in a formulaic expression.  Filtering does display time formats correctly, but will not return results when used with its built-in mathematical operators.  If it did, it is unlikely you would even need to post this scenario.

**FINAL THOUGHTS (SCENARIO OVER/INTENTIONALLY WRITTEN IN FIRST PERSON POINT OF VIEW):**  I’ve seen some posts on this site (and others) that provide solutions to similar problems by suggesting that the values be formatted to a number and proceeding from there, but I wrote this post not just to get some answers, but to see what experts think would be the most efficient way of meeting the objectives presented in this scenario.  I’d also be interested in knowing whether or not newer versions of Excel take some of the limitations I’ve encountered with Excel 2007 into consideration (e.g., conditional formatting/filtering).  Even some sort of pop-up box when you enter a number with a colon in it, might help a user think about formatting consistency.  A box or window with better explanations for the various options would be an improvement.  Even something as simple as having Excel ask the user “Is this a clock time or a time duration?” would help it (and the user) format correctly from the beginning.

Comment: I typed in 19:20 into a cell. The formula bar displays this as 7:20:00 PM.  The cell displays it as 19:20. A few in this column are time (13:30:55 format) but most are in h:mm. (I've changed all formats in this column to h:mm (for durations of time <60 minutes). That's the original column. Those cells were copied & pasted in a column next to it. In this column, for times <60 minutes, format was simply changed to  [m]:ss.  For times >60 minutes I've multiplied the time by 60  (=A1*60) and then changed that number format to [m]:ss.  All in 2nd column are now in same format. ? 4U in next comment.

Comment: Even w/the few in 13:30:55 format, time is displayed in the formula bar as a clock time.  E.g., 2:44:00 (is in the 13:30:55 format) is in the formula bar as 2:44:00 AM. Regardless, I get 164:00 when I change the format to [m]:ss, which matches all the others (the goal). What would I do if I had thousands of mismatched time formats. In my case, it was easy, I just hand selected those I saw that were >60 minutes and fixed them one at a time, but isn't there a way to display and sort by time format?

Comment: You are correct, the content in the comments and the question is not consistent, but at the time I wrote it, it somehow worked for me (and by the comments I read from some others the formula mentioned has been helpful to others as well).  Nevertheless, a second look at it the following day, helped me see a simpler solution to the problem.  I'll revamp the original question, even though I think what I've written previously might help somebody in the future because it generated a lot of positive comments at the site I retrieved it from.

Comment: You'll notice that I revamped the content/details for the question quite a bit. I attempted to give this question a context that would seem universal, practical, and useful and go beyond the particular details of the problem that directed my attention to this in the first place and which has since been solved to my satisfaction. More records and larger uncertainty regarding how they were entered, however, would be a problem far more likely in a real world situation if steps had not been taken to establish consistency prior to entry and might require a rapid, but reasonably accurate solution.